# raise ProgrammingError( mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: python, mysql, connector

i am trying to populate data in mysql from python using csv.
till tuple my program is working fine. am able to see data
but while uploading in sql. its giving error "Not all parameters used in sql statement"

```
with open("USERS.csv", "r") as f:
    val = []
    data = csv.reader(f)
    for row in data:
        val.append(tuple(row))
        print(tuple(row))
        cursor = mydb.cursor()
        sql=("insert into users (user_id, user_name, user_email,user_password,user_address,is_vendor)"
            " values(%s, %s , %s , %s , %s ,%d)")  
        cursor.execute(sql,tuple(row))
```

i al ready described above

Comment: Can you show the result of `print(tuple(row))`?

Comment: C:\Users\HP\Downloads\
('order_id', 'customer_id', 'vendor_id', 'total_value', 'order_qunatity', 'reward_point')
('1', '11', '5', '36480', '2', '200')
('2', '9', '5', '73291', '5', '100')
('3', '7', '5', '89414', '3', '100')
('4', '10', '4', '42084', '3', '100')
('5', '7', '5', '43547', '1', '100')
('6', '6', '5', '82280', '4', '200')
('7', '7', '2', '127616', '2', '200')
('8', '11', '2', '138303', '3', '200')
('9', '11', '1', '88289', '5', '100')
('10', '7', '2', '99797', '1', '100')

Comment: cursor.execute(mysql,tuple(row))
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 274, in execute
    raise ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
[Finished in 452ms]